# add predicate if property filled

Tags: c#, linq

Supposse, I have a class:

```
public class PersonalInfo
{
   public string Firsname {get;set;}
   public string Lastname {get;set;}
   public string Email {get;set;}
   public string Phone {get;set;}
}
```

The data come from file.
And, I need to select data from file by this property:

```
private IList<PersonalInfo> FindByPersonalData(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string phone)
{
...
}
```

Several properties can be empty, but if they filled then search by them. I can check every combination, but it's ugly. What is the best solution?
Thanks

Comment: linq to objects or linq to sql?

Comment: @devundef - OP mentions that the data comes from a file. No ORM appears to be involved.

Comment: @devundef - I'm not using ORM in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical sub-query would be to use a short-circuit on each field.  Making some assumptions about your data structures, that could look something like this:

```
var result = from p in PersonalInfoList
         where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) || firstName == p.FirstName)
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) || lastName == p.LastName)
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || email == p.Email)
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone) || phone == p.Phone)
         select p
```

Or, depending on your Linq preference:

```
var result = PersonalInfoList.Where(p =>
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) || firstName == p.FirstName)
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) || lastName == p.LastName)
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || email == p.Email)
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone) || phone == p.Phone))
```

So, if any parameter is null/empty, the comparison with the data will be skipped.

Comment: I tryed this code before posting the question.This is not work, see demo please https://compilify.net/3b/107

Comment: Why does it not work?  The code you linked to will not return the record because it's looking for `FirstName == "Test"` but you set `FirstName` to `"Test2"`.

Comment: Sorry, I found error. I have a `MaskedTextBox` for `Phone` and it contain separator for numbers even if it's empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish your task more elegantly, accumulating filter expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<PersonalInfo, bool>> filterExperssion = PredicateExtensions.True<PersonalInfo>();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
                filterExperssion = filterExperssion.And(p => p.FirstName == firstName);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
                ......
```

You need this little class-helper to build predicate

```
public static class PredicateExtensions
            {
                public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
                public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

                public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression2)
                {
                    var invokedExpression = Expression.Invoke(expression2, expression1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                          (Expression.Or(expression1.Body, invokedExpression), expression1.Parameters);
                }

                public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression1,
                                                                    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression2)
                {
                    var invokedExpression = Expression.Invoke(expression2, expression1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                          (Expression.And(expression1.Body, invokedExpression), expression1.Parameters);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The @Dan Puzey's asnwer fits well in this case. But is good to know that you can incrementaly build the linq query:

```
var result = source_list as IEnumerable<IPersonalInfo>;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
   result = result.Where(p => p.FirstName == firstName);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
   result = result.Where(p => p.LastName == lastName);

... other ifs for other fields ...

return result.ToList();
```